# Resolve possible strict violation (and help Batman save Gotham)

Tags: javascript, strict, iife

I've got the following (simplified) `Batman.js` file:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  window.Batman = function(){
    // Global references
    this.version = "1.0.1";
  };

  Batman.prototype.saveGotham = function(params) {
    var _ = this; // Works fine
    destroyGotham.call(_, params);
  };

  // Private
  function destroyGotham(params){
    var _ = this; // <!-- "possible strict violation"
  }

}());
```

JSHint complains about a `possible strict violation` at the indicated line. How do I get around this without dropping the `"use strict"`?

P.S: I'd like the troublesome `var _ = this` to reference the `Batman` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value passed as `this` to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object.
For a normal function, `this` is always an object, and it's the global object if called with an undefined or null `this`, in other words `this` is usually the `window` by default in non-strict mode.

Not only is automatic boxing a performance cost, but exposing the global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global object provides access to functionality that "secure" JavaScript environments must restrict.
Thus for a strict mode function, the specified `this` is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, `this` will be undefined by default.

This means that using `this` that way, just setting it to a variable

```
var _ = this;
```

in most cases will lead to `this` being undefined, which why jshint is saying it's a *"possible"* violation, as it would be if you didn't call it with `call` and provided a this-value.

Ignore jshint, what you're doing is fine.

Comment: And how do I fix it?

Comment: You ignore jshint as you're calling the function in such a way that `this` will be defined,

Comment: Thanks -- I found out that you can add `/*jshint validthis:true */` on the line above the complaining `var _ = this;` to suppress the error.

Comment: Yes, if you just have to pass jshint, you can skip the `this` test

Comment: Alternatively, add `"validthis": "_"` to your jshint config